# How re-investing governance tokens make profits?

Tags: polygon, decentralized-exchange, defi

I am studying Beefy Yield Aggregator. It defines its strategies as investing the underlying asset in Balancer to get governance token and swapping it to get the same tokens again and get the same underlying assets again and again investing those assets to get the governance tokens and so on.

So my question is how Beefy is making profits. If I want my underlying assets back so how can I get it since I have swapped my all governance tokens?

Comment: Beefy makes profits by taking a % of rewards I believe. In any case you'll get a better answer if you ask in their discord/telegram